# Remove Capabilities from WP admin for specific user role

Tags: users, user-roles, capabilities

I am trying to **remove** some **menu-links** capabilities from the wp-admin for a **user role called wsm**. I have tried many ways and when i just add the **code below** it will remove those links from the menu for all user roles.

The problem is that it also strips the menus from my **own admin as Super Admin**. So basically it removes the menu links from any role.

I tried to add this line: ***{ if (current_user_can('administrator'))***
but it didn't change anything. Maybe i added it in the wrong place?

I need to remove links also based on certain **post types** as you can see below.

```
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'remove_row_actions', 10, 1 );
function remove_row_actions_testimonials( $actions )
{ 
    if( get_post_type() === 'wiki-testimonials' )
        unset( $actions['view'] );
        unset( $actions['edit'] );
    return $actions;
}
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'remove_row_actions', 10, 1 );
function remove_row_actions_staff( $actions )
  {
    if( get_post_type() === 'wiki-staff' )
        unset( $actions['view'] );
        unset( $actions['delete'] );
        unset( $actions['trash'] );
        unset( $actions['edit'] );
    return $actions;
}
```

If someone can help me to produce the correct solution I would be very greatfull.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition on capabilities in order to exclude the admin from the unset action for example

```
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'remove_row_actions', 10, 2 );
function remove_row_actions_staff( $actions, $post ){
  //This line stops function execution if user has some admin capabilities 
  if( current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ):
    return $actions;
   endif; 

  if( $post->post_type() === 'wiki-testimonials' )
    unset( $actions['view'] );
    unset( $actions['edit'] );
  return $actions;
}
```

Comment: Hi Cravon,

Thanks for your reply. I have tried your code, but this also removes my menu-links as administrator?

M.

Comment: Hi Marc, you right : give a try to my edited version : the problem was a void return. I mixed up filter and action sorry.

Comment: Hi,
Tried that, but it didn't work. I made a small alteration and changed "edit-user" for "administrator"
That made it work to hide menu-links from my wsm user and keep all capabilities for administrator. It just does not apply to a specific post type, but for all the post types. 

add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'remove_row_actions', 10, 1 );
function remove_row_actions( $actions ){
  if( current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ):
    return $actions;
   endif; 
if( get_post_type() === 'wiki-testimonials' ){
        unset( $actions['view'] );
  return $actions;
}}

Comment: Hi did you try to get post type with the $post object (second parameter on the filter) ? I show this on my edit.

Comment: Hi CRavon,

Unfortunately it produces a critical error.

Thnx. Marc

Comment: Did you change the number of argument to "2" in the add filter line ?

Comment: Yes, I did. Still get an error saying "critical error" I have it working, but not for each seperate post-type. For now i could live with that. Hopefully there will be a full solution somehow. 
Thnx